# This makefile does not update object files

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I generated a makefile out of a codeblocks project (written in c++11), so I can use Atom as IDE. But it does not update the object files when I i.e. change the default constructors parameter in the header file, which is really annoying. It just links the existing object files again. But even if I make a little change to the .cpp file, it recompiles the object without recognizing the changes in the header file. The only quick fix I found is to delete the object file manually, so it really generates it completely new. The header part I currently often change looks like this:

```
VRParticles(): VRParticles(123){}
```

The whole makefile is available here (generated using cbp2make): https://github.com/Pfeil/polyvr/blob/master/Makefile
(Please note that I am just a fairly new contributor and not responsible for the way this is programmed ;) )

I use the makefile mostly with one of those two commands:

```
make -j 3 build_debug
make debug
```

Note that everything compiles fine when I delete VRParticles.o or do `make clean` and `make debug`.

Please note that my experience with makefiles is very low. The makefile basically works like this (remember the link to the full version above):

```
OBJ_DEBUG = # all object files

build_debug: before_debug out_debug after_debug

debug: before_build build_debug after_build

out_debug: before_debug $(OBJ_DEBUG) $(DEP_DEBUG)
    $(LD) $(LIBDIR_DEBUG) -o $(OUT_DEBUG) $(OBJ_DEBUG)  $(LDFLAGS_DEBUG) $(LIB_DEBUG)

$(OBJDIR_DEBUG)/src/addons/Bullet/Particles/VRParticles.o: src/addons/Bullet/Particles/VRParticles.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_DEBUG) $(INC_DEBUG) -c src/addons/Bullet/Particles/VRParticles.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_DEBUG)/src/addons/Bullet/Particles/VRParticles.o
```

I'd really like give more information, but I have no idea what else could be important, so please ask if you need more. My question basically is how I need to modify the makefile (I guess this file contains the issue) so the object files get updated if needed. Without recompiling everything.

I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

Answer (score 2):

If we look at your dependencies for `VRParticles.o`:

```
VRParticles.o : src/addons/Bullet/Particles/VRParticles.cpp
```

You are telling `make` that the object file only depends on `VRParticles.cpp`. So when you update `VRParticles.h`, that doesn't matter - you never listed `VRParticles.h` as a dependency! Thankfully, gcc can generate those dependencies for you automatically:

```
$(CC) $(other flag stuff) -MP -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d) -o $@ -c $<
```

That will create a file `VRParticles.d` which will have make-style rules for dependencies, in this case something like:

```
VRParticles.o : VRParticles.d
```

So at that point, all we need is to include them:

```
DEPENDENCY_FILES = $(....)
-include $(DEPENDENCY_FILES)
```

Comment: I already tried to add the header file as dependency, and it indeed gets rebuilt, but the changes are not recognized. For example I change the constructor parameter from 123 to 400, but after compilation only 123 Particles get spawned. So it would not be enough to add it as a dependency, right? About your solution: I'm not sure how to use the line with the gcc. Do I just add the flags to the existing ones? Or do I need an extra line in every target?

Comment: @verpfeilt You want to restructure your makefile so that you have ONE rule that builds ALL the object files. And yeah, that one gcc line will produce both the .o and the .d file.